# Is it possible to find a solution to these inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Solving an exercise I found myself with this problem: the solution $c$ needs to verify both $$\sum_{k=1}^c n\lambda^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda}}{k!}\leq \alpha$$ and $$1-\sum_{k=1}^{c} n\lambda^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda}}{k!}\geq \alpha$$

The values $n,\lambda,\alpha$ are known. Can an equation like this be solved for $c$?

Comment: Yes of course....

Comment: @hyprfrcb:  I'm not confident these *inequalities* can be "solved for $c$".  It is not stated what values $n,\lambda,\alpha$ are, or even that their values are known to someone who is asked to solve for $c$.

Comment: @hardmath I edited that. The values $n,\lambda,\alpha$ are known. Also, there was a typo, the denominator is $k!$ instead of $k$.

Comment: So with $C := n e^{n \lambda}$ you try to solve $C \sum_{k=1}^c \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} \le \min (\alpha, 1-\alpha)$  ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that's what I want to solve.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ positive? Then the series is increasing, and a solution would exist exactly if $C \lambda \le \min(\alpha, 1 - \alpha)$

Comment: @MartinR I don't know if $\lambda$ is positive in this case. This is part of a series of equations I need to solve, for general $\lambda$, but the inequation I posted were found under the assumption $\lambda>0$. The inequalities invert if $\lambda < 0$.
Is there a closed form tor the solution?

Comment: Closed forms for the partial sums of the exponential series are not "nice", see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50746/general-term-formula-of-s-n-sum-limits-i-1n-fracaii.

Comment: The second summation originally ran to upper limit $c+1$, but now to $c$ (just like the first summation).  Is this perhaps an unintentional edit?

Comment: @hardmath It's not. I changed it because I was supposed to have $\text{Pr}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\geq c+1 |\lambda=\lambda_0)>\alpha$ which I took to be $1-\text{Pr}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\leq c |\lambda=\lambda_0)=1-\sum_{k=1}^{c} n\lambda^k\frac{e^{-n\lambda}}{k!}\geq \alpha$ because the $X_i$ are independent Poisson distributed variables.