# Summation of finite power seires

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Is it possible to find a close form solution for $S_1$.

$S_1$ is defined as follows:

$S_1=\sum_{k=b}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$ ; Where $0<x<b<\infty$

If $b=0$ then $S_2 = e^x$. But how do we solve $S_1$ for the condition given above? I think we can use upper incomplete gamma function but not sure how to get a solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is what you are after, but I would consider 
$$
S_1 = e^x - \sum_0 ^b \frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
a closed form for your sum.

Comment: How do I find the sum for $x^k/k!$ term ? Do you want me to see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/closed-form-of-a-partial-sum-of-the-power-series-of-expx for the second term?

Comment: @Ria You could use the expression there, which here corresponds to $\sum_0 ^b \frac{x^k}{k!} = \frac{e^x \int_x ^\infty t^b e^{-t} d t }{ \Gamma (b+1) }$. I am not aware of any other one, however. I think it is generally accepted/defined that finite sums are closed forms, although perhaps not necessarily very elegant ones. In this case, we would get that $$ S_1 = e^{x} \left( 1 - \frac{\int_x ^\infty t^b e^{-t} d t }{ \Gamma (b+1) } \right) = \frac{ e^{x} }{ \Gamma (b+1) } \left( \Gamma (b+1) - \int_x ^\infty t^b e^{-t} d t \right) . $$